# Component is rendering before and after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, reactjs

So im working on my first project after my code school and im hitting a snag right away with my ajax call. it seems my render is rendering before the ajax call and after, therefore i get an error when i try to display info that i grabbed from the database

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import $ from 'jquery';

class StepFive extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
     ingredients: []

      }
}
   ingredientsGrab() {
    var me = this;
    $.ajax({
     method: 'GET',
     url: 'http://localhost:3002/api/ingredients',
    })
    .then(function(ingredients){
            me.setState({ingredients: ingredients})
    })
   }
    componentWillMount() {
        this.ingredientsGrab()
    }

render() {
  console.log(this.state.ingredients[0], 'in render1')
      return(
        <div className='stepFiveBox'>
          <span>bubbly</span>
        </div>
      )
  }
}

export default StepFive
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me5x7.jpg)

Comment: Fix the indent so that the code becomes readable.

Comment: Try putting your ajax call in `componentWillMount`.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal behavior when your component is rendered and then you fetching data and re-render this component with this data. But for this you should to use `componentDidMount`.

Check docs:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: still getting the same issue